# Is there any good hosting for asp.net and MySQL

Tags: web-hosting, mysql, asp.net, shared-hosting

I have an account with a hosting company and I have made a project in asp.net and I have used MySQL for the database but... the hosting company has not given my account enough privileges to create a new user or to create new stored procedure.

When I contacted them I was informed the following:

> Due to the shared nature of our environment we had to make some modifications to your procedure (namely the definer). We also had to review your procedure to determine if it would be compatible with our environment.
>
> While your procedures will work (via phpMyAdmin or some other interface), it is unlikely they will be accessible via the Connector/.NET (ADO.NET) that your application is likely using. This is due to a security restriction with how that connector works in shared environments.
>
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net-programming-stored.html
>
> "Note
>
> When you call a stored procedure, the command object makes an additional SELECT call to determine the parameters of the stored procedure. You must ensure that the user calling the procedure has the SELECT privilege on the mysql.proc table to enable them to verify the parameters. Failure to do this will result in an error when calling the procedure."
>
> Unfortunately, giving read privileges on the mysql.proc table will give you access to the data of our other customers and that is not an acceptable risk. If your application can only work using stored procedures, then MSSQL will probably be the better option for your site.
>
> I apologize for the inconvenience and the wait to have this ticket completed.

This is one of the procedures that my application will need to perform on the database, I believe this is simple and it should not harm others in 'Shared Environments':

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SpcategoriesRead`(
    IN PaRactioncode VARCHAR(5),
    IN PaRCatID BIGINT,
    IN PaRSearchText TEXT
)
BEGIN

-- CREATING TEMPORARY TABLE TO SAVE DATA FROM THE ACTIONCODE SELECTS --

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP;

CREATE temporary table tmp
(
    CatID BIGINT primary key not null,
    CatTitle TEXT,
    CatDescription TEXT,
    CatTitleAr TEXT,
    CatDescriptionAr TEXT,
    PictureID BIGINT,
    Published BOOLEAN,
    DisplayOrder BIGINT,
    CreatedOn DATE
);

IF PaRactioncode = 1 THEN -- Retrive all DATA from the database --
    INSERT INTO tmp
    SELECT CatID,CatTitle,CatDescription,CatTitleAr,CatDescriptionAr,PictureID,Published,DisplayOrder,CreatedOn
    FROM tbcategories;
ELSEIF PaRactioncode = 2 THEN -- Retrive all from the database By ID --
    INSERT INTO tmp
    SELECT CatID,CatTitle,CatDescription,CatTitleAr,CatDescriptionAr,PictureID,Published,DisplayOrder,CreatedOn  
    FROM tbcategories
    WHERE CatID=PaRCatID;
ELSEIF PaRactioncode = 3 THEN -- NOSET YET --
    INSERT INTO tmp
    SELECT CatID,CatTitle,CatDescription,CatTitleAr,CatDescriptionAr,PictureID,Published,DisplayOrder,CreatedOn 
    FROM tbcategories
    WHERE Published=1 
    ORDER BY DisplayOrder; 
 END IF;

 IF PaRSearchText IS NOT NULL THEN
    set PaRSearchText=concat('%', PaRSearchText ,'%');
    SELECT CatID,CatTitle,CatDescription,CatTitleAr,CatDescriptionAr,PictureID,Published,DisplayOrder,CreatedOn
    FROM tmp
    WHERE Concat(CatTitle, CatDescription, CatTitleAr, CatDescriptionAr)
    LIKE  PaRSearchText;
 ELSE 
    SELECT CatID,CatTitle,CatDescription,CatTitleAr,CatDescriptionAr,PictureID,Published,DisplayOrder,CreatedOn
    FROM tmp;
    END IF; 

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp; 

 END
```

So my question is: Does anyone know any good hosting companies that they have personally used that will enable me to publish my Asp.net and MySQL project without these limitations?

Answer (score 1):

It might not harm any other users but if you're on a shared database with other users, I doubt they'd want you to be able to create other user accounts. I would advise running this proc under another account.

To answer your question, I think Rackspace cloud does what you want.